# Using variables alongside strings in a regex in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

My dataset consists of a number of email addresses whose domains I am trying to scrub:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
email <- c('jim@chase.com','steve@aol.com','stacy@gmail.com/','chris@yahoo.com','emilio@verizon.net/')
sample <- data.frame(id,email)
```

I'm trying to remove rows based on an imported .txt file containing domains; for example,  the domains.txt consists of

```
chase.com verizon.net
```

I read the .txt file with

```
domains <- read_file('C:\\\\me\\domains.txt')
domains <- strsplit(domains, ' ')
```

but then I am at a loss as to how to successfully clean these. I have tried two solutions, one with a `regex` code and one without:

```
sample <- sample[!(paste0('^',domains,'$') %in% sample$email)]

sample$domains <- grepl(paste0('^',domains,'$'),sample$email)
sample <- subset(sample, domains == FALSE, select = c(id,email))
```

The first transforms my data into a tibble (resulting in the `Column indexes must be at most 4 if positive, not 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` error whenever I try to display it), while the second returns `FALSE` for all domains, including those that contain the domains listed in the `domains` variable.

How can I create a "search and destroy" `regex` using a variable when the string has text on either side of the variable that needs to be read as well?

Comment: Is `read_file` from `readr`?

Comment: And are you trying to remove the domains, or drop the observations where those domains are found?

Comment: It is readr::read_file. And I am trying to drop the cases that contain those domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We `paste` the elements of 'pat' to a single string with `paste` separated by `|` to match either one of the elements with the 'email' column, using `grepl` returns a logical index, negate (`!`) to change TRUE to FALSE and viceversa, subset the rows of the 'sample'

```
sample[!grepl(paste(pat, collapse="|"), sample$email), , drop = FALSE]
```

#### data

```
pat <- c('chase.com', 'verizon.net')
```

Comment: I'll give you credit for the grep, but I want to add that this only works with the concatenation `pat`. If I'm reading a domains.txt file into domains, like I mentioned above, it reads as a list rather than a concatenation, leading to the code `sample[!grepl(paste(domains[[1]], collapse="|"), sample$email), , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: @Yehuda  It is not clear about the structure of `domains`.  If it is a `list`, you can `unlist` and then `paste` it.